# How do I use options for in_place_editing in my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to change how the in_place_editing view looks like. I want to change the button text and other view related things in the in_place_editing plugin

I am trying with this code

```
 <%= in_place_editor_field :contact,:address_line1,:saving_text =>"Update"%>
```

But nothing is getting changed. How else can I pass options to in_place_editor_field

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Did you place the following in your controller?

```
in_place_edit_for :contact_, :address_line1
```

(as described [here](http://github.com/rails/in_place_editing/blob/master/lib/in_place_editing.rb))

Also, do you have any warning or error in the Javascript console of your browser?

Comment: Yes I am using http://github.com/rails/in_place_editing for in place editing, i want to specify options in the view template so that I can resize the textfiled, change the button text etc.,.. i tried with above code and it was not working

Comment: From your example I think you mean :save_text => "Update". As for size, etc. you may want to look into css for some of that.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "Not working"? Can you post screenshot and the HTML code of the page? any javascript warning in your browser? what version of rails are you using?